# Windows Phone 8 WPF MediaElement not playing video

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, video

I have created a MediaElement in my Windows Phone 8.1 app, and I am trying to play an mp4 video. When I press the button to play the video, it shows the video's first frame (splash screen), but it never goes beyond that, and it looks like a still picture. What could I be doing wrong? I don't get any error from my MediaFailed method, either.

```
private void openButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
shakeImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        timer.Stop();
        timerReset.Stop();
        rotateImage.Stop();


        mediaElement.Stop();
        Uri explosion = new Uri(BaseUri, "Explode.mp4");
        mediaElement.Source = explosion;
        mediaElement.Play();
        mediaElement.MediaFailed += mediaElement_MediaFailed;

}

void mediaElement_MediaFailed)object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are playing audio file from your phone you should change "UriKind " to "Relative" like this

```
 Uri explosion = new Uri( "Explode.mp4",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

// or you could use this way

```
Stream stream = isoStore1.OpenFile("Explode.mp4", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read );

                this.mediaElement.Stop();
                this.mediaElement.SetSource(stream);
mediaElement.Play();
```

stream.Close();

Comment: I'm playing a video file with audio, but using Uri explosion = new Uri( "Explode.mp4",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); gives me an argument exception. With the second method, it claims that a SetSource function with one argument doesn't exist; also, what would isoStore1 be?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to Windows Phone 8 being picky about file formats and not throwing errors even though they were incorrect. I converted it to a certain wmv type and it seems to work now.